# Does iPad support 4096x4096 view?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

Does iPad support view with a 4096x4096 frame?

Comment: Wow, who vote to move to superuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try and find out, but for general purposes, I wouldn't go that large without a `CATiledLayer`.  If you don't know about `CATiledLayer`s, basically you need to override the static function `+(class)LayerClass` in your subclass of `UIView` and return `[CATiledLayer class]`.  This class is defined in the QuartzCore framework, which is not included by default.

When using `CATiledLayer`s, you can make the view much larger than would otherwise be supported, because the layer handles drawing the view in small chunks (default of 256x256 tiles) rather than all at once.  It's basically what the `UIWebView` and Google Maps use (I assume.  It's in that vein anyway).